# Делаю слайдер на slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Делаю очередной слайдер на slick slider. Столкнулся с проблемами вывода риснука монитора на слайдер как бэкграунд. Не получается сделать так чтобы моник висел над сдайдером и при скроллинге слайды на наезжали на моник, а шли под ним. и как бы все это дело сделать responsive.

вот мой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/059tmowq/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".mac-slider").slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px'
  });
});
```

Comment: монитор надо ставить фоном на обёртку слайдера. а сам слайдер позиционировать внутри таким образом, чтобы ширина/высота просматриваемого контента совпадала с размером внутри монитора. для адаптива придётся изменять размер видимой части слайдера, чтобы подогнать под размер монитора. ну и картинки надо подогнать по размеру под ваш монитор на фоне

Comment: @lexxl а сейчас она на обёртке же, но слайды же все равно наезжают на него...